# Android Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/RequestLine;

Tags: android, android-ion

On **Android 9 on a OnePlus5**, when I try a remote connection using the `ion` library, I receive this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/RequestLine;
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion$Config$1.createAsyncHttpRequest + 559(Ion.java:559)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.prepareRequest + 282(IonRequestBuilder.java:282)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.execute + 616(IonRequestBuilder.java:616)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.execute + 606(IonRequestBuilder.java:606)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.as + 891(IonRequestBuilder.java:891)
   at io.dishup.dishup.Network.request + 79(Network.java:79)
   at io.dishup.dishup.EndpointCustomer.setNewCustomer + 29(EndpointCustomer.java:29)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup.sendTokensToServer + 129(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:129)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup.access$400 + 29(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:29)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup$5.onComplete + 114(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:114)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run + 4(:4)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6898(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 537(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.RequestLine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.dishup.dishup-OqmfH61IongnKfllcQH-mQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.dishup.dishup-OqmfH61IongnKfllcQH-mQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass + 169(BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 379(ClassLoader.java:379)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass + 312(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion$Config$1.createAsyncHttpRequest + 559(Ion.java:559)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.prepareRequest + 282(IonRequestBuilder.java:282)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.execute + 616(IonRequestBuilder.java:616)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.execute + 606(IonRequestBuilder.java:606)
   at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder.as + 891(IonRequestBuilder.java:891)
   at io.dishup.dishup.Network.request + 79(Network.java:79)
   at io.dishup.dishup.EndpointCustomer.setNewCustomer + 29(EndpointCustomer.java:29)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup.sendTokensToServer + 129(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:129)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup.access$400 + 29(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:29)
   at io.dishup.dishup.GoogleSignInToDishup$5.onComplete + 114(GoogleSignInToDishup.java:114)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run + 4(:4)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6898(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 537(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I really don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest ion release. That dependency was removed.

Answer (score 3):

try adding this line to your build.gradle:

```
android {

 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' //(this worked for us when we had a similar issue with apache)
```

alternatively , try this in your manifest :

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

the reason for this is due to the fact that, from android 9, that library is removed from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default, so it has to be added.

see : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using Apache HTTP client in your code.

> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.http.RequestLine"

Enabling [legacy mode for the use of this library](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client) is not recomended, in fact [since Android 9, Apache HTTP client library was completely removed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p) from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.

**The real solution is by implementing [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) class.
If you are using the [ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion), you can have two better options that are already using  [**HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection)** class.**

- [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) that [use HttpUrlConnection](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/data/HttpUrlFetcher.java).
- and [**Picasso**](https://square.github.io/picasso/) that [use HttpUrlConnection](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/UrlConnectionDownloader.html).

---

The use of [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and  [**Picasso**](https://square.github.io/picasso/) is similar to the ion library.

---

**Glide**

Loading image from resources  (`/drawable` directory):

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

Loading image from url :

```
Glide.with(context).load(<image Url>).into(imageView);
```

define this dependency into your  `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    ...
}
```

---

**Picasso :**

Loading image from resources  (`/drawable` directory):

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

Loading image from url :

```
Picasso.get().load(<image Url>).into(imageView);
```

you need to define this dependency into your  `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
    ...
}
```

with both options you will get the same result:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the exception is `ClassNotFoundException`. This exception occurs when you want to create an object of a class or access fields of a class that no exist. but wait, if the class does not exist then my code will be not compiled. yes, you right so the class exists but something deletes that class. something like `Progaurd`.

So you must add some progaurd rules to keep that class. Add these code into your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Also instead of using maven repository, download jar files and put them into `/app/libs' folder then write following line in your build.gradle file.

```
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
```